# Singleton events

Tags: c#, events

I am refactoring some old code, where I have a lot of static events like this

```
public static event Action Updated;
public static void OnUpdated()
{
    if (Updated != null)
        Updated();
}
```

I found out what using [lazy singletons](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx#lazy) is often better than using static classes:

- no memory is consumed until first `Instance` call;
- private serialization/deserialization.

So that I refactor those to singletons and now I have Code Analysis complains.

Such events clearly offend [CS1009](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182133.aspx) but I have some doubts:

- for static events `sender` doesn't makes sense, why and in what scenario would singleton `sender` be of any use? I can only think about deserialization, but it's an internal class implementation (moreover class is sealed), so I can take care to not use events and if I need one, I can create private event.
- creating `e` (deriving from `EventArgs`) is unnecessary complication to simply pass parameters, the biggest part I hate is to move it into namespace level, the only thing which `EventArgs` adds (could be useful sometimes) is `Empty` and then you have dozens of classes `...EventArgs`. I could think what sometimes you need [Cancel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.cancel.aspx) or [Handled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.handledeventargs.handled.aspx) mechanics, but it was neverd needed for me.

When using event does everybody expect `(object sender, SomeEventArgs args)` and this is the only reason?

To summarize, here is my *main* question (but I would appreciate clarifying other questions as well): CS1009 and singletons, should I fix events or simply suppress the message?

P.S.: related subjects: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2789642/1997232), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4462050/1997232) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16959822/1997232).

---

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17856823/1997232) question. According to [event design guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229011.aspx) I have to use `Event<T>` (disregards to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6048386/1997232) question), where `T` is based on `EventArgs` class.

Regarding `sender` in static events:

> On static events, the `sender` parameter should be null.

This is a  *design guideline*, which may not looks pretty **to me**, but will be very welcomed by anybody else (who is reading/maintaining my code).

It breaks both [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) principles as for me. And the more I think about it, the less and less I am sure of what to do.

Comment: It depends on project. If it is a huge ddd project I'd definetely preserve these (sender and event args) even though they are not used (to preserve the architecture). But if it just a simple console app it's different story

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would fix your error. The general design guideline is indeed the `(object sender, EventArgs e)` signature.

It's a convention and is all about code consistency, code readability...etc. Following this pattern will help other people attaching handlers to your events.

Some general tips/answers:

- For a static event, you should indeed use `null` as `sender` (because there is no sender instance *per definition*).
- If you have nothing to pass for the `e` parameter, use `EventArgs.Empty` instead of `new EventArgs()` or `null`.
- You could use `EventHandler` and `EventHandler<T>` to simplify the definition of your events.
- For the sake of simplicity, you could use a custom `EventArgs<T>` class inheriting from `EventArgs` if you want to pass a single value to your event handler.

If you want to use the singleton pattern with a `Lazy<T>` definition, here's a complete example. Do note no event is `static`, so the `sender` parameter contains a reference to the singleton instance:

```
public class EventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
    public EventArgs(T value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public T Value { get; set; }
}

public class EventArgs2 : EventArgs
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

internal static class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Singleton.Instance.MyEvent += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine("MyEvent with empty parameter");
        Singleton.Instance.MyEvent2 += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine("MyEvent2 with parameter {0}", e.Value);
        Singleton.Instance.MyEvent3 += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine("MyEvent3 with parameter {0}", e.Value);

        Singleton.Instance.Call();

        Console.Read();
    }
}

public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Singleton> lazy = new Lazy<Singleton>(() => new Singleton());

    public static Singleton Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Prevents a default instance of the <see cref="Singleton"/> class from being created.
    /// </summary>
    private Singleton()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Event without any associated data
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler MyEvent;

    /// <summary>
    /// Event with a specific class as associated data
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs2> MyEvent2;

    /// <summary>
    /// Event with a generic class as associated data
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs<int>> MyEvent3;

    public void Call()
    {
        if (this.MyEvent != null)
        {
            this.MyEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        if (this.MyEvent2 != null)
        {
            this.MyEvent2(this, new EventArgs2 { Value = 12 });
        }

        if (this.MyEvent3 != null)
        {
            this.MyEvent3(this, new EventArgs<int>(12));
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

---

EDIT:

You could also build some `EventArgs<T1, T2>` if you need to pass two values. Ultimately, `EventArgs<Tuple<>>` would also be possible, but for more than 2 values I would build a specific `XXXEventArgs` class instead as it's easier to read `XXXEventArgs.MyNamedBusinessProperty` than `EventArgs<T1, T2, T3>.Value2` or `EventArgs<Tuple<int, string, bool>>.Value.Item1`.

Regarding KISS/YAGNI: remember the `(object sender, EventArgs e)` convention *is all about code consistency*. If some developer uses your code to attach an handler to one of your events, I can assure you he will *just love* the fact that your event definition is **just like any other event definition in the BCL itself**, so he instantly knows how to properly use your code.

There even are others advantages than just code consistency/readability:

I inherited my custom `XXXEventArgs` classes from `EventArgs`, but you could build some base `EventArgs` class and inherit from it. For instance, see [`MouseEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs(v=vs.100).aspx) and all classes inheriting from it. Much better to reuse existing classes than to provide multiple delegate signatures with 5/6 identical properties. For instance:

```
public class MouseEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}

public class MouseClickEventArgs : MouseEventArgs
{
    public int ButtonType { get; set; }
}

public class MouseDoubleClickEventArgs : MouseClickEventArgs
{
    public int TimeBetweenClicks { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    public event EventHandler<MouseClickEventArgs> ClickEvent;
    public event EventHandler<MouseDoubleClickEventArgs> DoubleClickEvent;
}

public class Test2
{
    public delegate void ClickEventHandler(int X, int Y, int ButtonType);
    public event ClickEventHandler ClickEvent;

    // See duplicated properties below =>
    public delegate void DoubleClickEventHandler(int X, int Y, int ButtonType, int TimeBetweenClicks);
    public event DoubleClickEventHandler DoubleClickEvent;
}
```

Another point is, using `EventArgs` could simplify code maintainability. Imagine the following scenario:

```
public MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> MyEvent;
...
if (this.MyEvent != null)
{
    this.MyEvent(this, new MyEventArgs { MyProperty = "foo" });
}
...
someInstance.MyEvent += (sender, e) => SomeMethod(e.MyProperty);
```

In case you want to add some `MyProperty2` property to `MyEventArgs`, you could do it without modifying all your existing event listeners:

```
public MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty2 { get; set; }
}

public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> MyEvent;
...
if (this.MyEvent != null)
{
    this.MyEvent(this, new MyEventArgs { MyProperty = "foo", MyProperty2 = "bar" });
}
...
// I didn't change the event handler. If SomeMethod() doesn't need MyProperty2, everything is just fine already
someInstance.MyEvent += (sender, e) => SomeMethod(e.MyProperty);
```

Comment: `EventHandler<EventArgs<T>>` is cool, thanks. But for multiple parameters it will be so much hated `Tuple<>` right? Do you have an opinion in regards KISS and YAGNI. Both say I shouldn't do what you suggest for my `Updated` event (no sender - because `static` or singleton, and no args). You see I am looking for a kind of *final* argument to convince me, an unbeatable advantage.

Comment: @Sinatr I edited the answer to provide more information

Comment: I feel convinced. Thanks for all the effort!